# Bash Tab Auto-complete not working for apt

Tags: apt, bash, auto-completion

`apt-get install` and `apt-cache policy` do not complete package names.

I have double checked /etc/bash.bashrc, no irregularities.

Googled for answers but none suffice.

Any help/advice?

Comment: `aptitude` is not equal to `apt`. Which one is problematic?

Comment: Apologies. Apt commands in general.

Comment: Is completion set up for apt-get? `complete -p apt-get`

Comment: The result reads: 'complete -F _apt_get apt-get' Not sure what that means

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Actually, I found the solution ~

Install the auto-complete-el

```
sudo apt-get install auto-complete-el
```

[image: Install via the software center]

After installing this package, I got everything back to normal.

Comment: It works, but I don't get why, the `el` stands for Emacs Lisp...

Comment: Any ideas about autocompletion for `apt` itself? (as opposed to `apt-get`)

Answer (score 17):

Open `/etc/bash.bashrc` with gedit or other text editor and uncomment the following lines:

```
#if [ -f /etc/bash_completion ] && ! shopt -oq posix; then
#    . /etc/bash_completion
#fi
```

It works for me.

On Ubuntu 16.04 the it looks like this:

```
#if ! shopt -oq posix; then
#  if [ -f /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion ]; then
#    . /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion
#  elif [ -f /etc/bash_completion ]; then
#    . /etc/bash_completion
#  fi
#fi
```

Comment: I can't find any `/etc/bash.bashrc`. You sure about that?

Comment: Adding those lines to `~/.bashrc` should work, too.

Comment: Relogin was required, but then it worked!

Answer (score 2):

Is your shell prompt looking like `$` instead of `user@host:~$`? If yes, then it could be case of wrong shell causing problem with autocompletion. Try changing login shell to `/bin/bash` from `/bin/sh` as below.

```
sudo chsh -s /bin/bash *username*
```

Comment: Dear Downvoter, please leave a comment helping me avoid repeating, the perceived mistake.

Answer (score 2):

The cause might be that you are missing the package `bash-completion`.
In that case, you can try installing it with

```
sudo apt-get install bash-completion
```

followed by

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

for enabling it. (Or just log out and in again).

Comment: Is this a question or an answer?

Comment: Rephrased to read more like an answer